# Can you free the buffer you pass to xmlParseDoc()?

Tags: libxml2

For example:

```
xmlDocPtr parseDoc() {
    buf = malloc(12);
    strncpy(buf, "<document/>", 12);
    xmlDocPtr doc = xmlParseDoc(buf);
    free(buf); /*** is this safe? ***/
    return doc;
}
```

The [documentation](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlParseDoc) is a bit vague and it's not clear whether the resulting tree contains all the information from the original buffer or whether it needs the buffer to remain valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can free the buffer after parsing. I'd also recommend to use [xmlReadMemory](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlReadMemory) for parsing in-memory documents. It  has some useful options.